# Is this a sign of my computer being hijacked?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, malware

This is not the first time this has happened. I do have a VMware machine, but they are both off and this does not happen every day, so I don't think this is the problem. This is all the information I was able to get from it:
[image: f_IMG]

This is still active even when I disable my internet connection.

[image]

[image]

I have 2 antivirus programs active, Malwarebytes Premium and Avast Premier, and they didn't detect anything. I'm running the scan on Malwarebytes and then I will try Avast.

Even after removing that Ethernet 2 it still didn't fix the problem, so I restarted the computer. My Chrome still looked like the image, so I checked Network and Sharing Centre and there was no Ethernet 2.
I restarted the computer again and finally it was working, however I still suspect it is active or something. Is there anywhere I can check to find out what is it and where is it from?

After running the Malwarebytes Threat Scan I get this result:

[image]

[image]

Both of them detected threats in Chrome. Is my Chrome infected?

Are there any logs or anything which can give me more detail about what just happened?

Comment: What exactly is your problem here? No connection? Are you trying to use a wired or wireless connection? Did you try another browser? Did you try another website?

Comment: No connection something intercepted my connection I think, and probably using my computer as a zombie or something I really don't know but I need to know before anything further happens without me knowing.

Comment: Could you describe your network setup and bit more in detail? If I understand you correctly, the screenshots are from your host system. There are two virtual machines existing on your computer but they are not running. You have to LAN cards installed which provide the network connections Ethernet 1 and Ethernet 2? The LAN card providing Ethernet 2 connection is connected via a cable to your router that provides the Internet access? Why do you expect that the connection problems of your host system are related to your virtual machines?

Comment: @daniel.neumann i am connected using normal WiFi connection(screenshot 1 my connection is only the top one) not Ethernet i don't know what Ethernet 2 this the second time I seen it, and the same problem happened last time too, except when I removed that connection/ disabled it the problem was fixed. This time I had to restart the computer twice?

Comment: `Ethernet 2` is your LAN adapter, and its named `Ethernet 2`, because at some point you connected to a new LAN network  You are not being hacked beyond what Avast is doing to your secure SSL/TLS traffic, strongly suggest, removing that horrible piece of software.

Comment: @Ramhound Whenever this Ethernet 2 appears this problem occurs and it seems like it's `evolving` since it doesn't stop as easily as before. Considering the fact I have not used VM for 2-3 months how is it activating the Ethernet connection, their was also log talking about the user configuration for it (that's all it says) and when I check that directory I see the files has been modified (that might be normal) but since I'm not using it right now I disabled it's services for now. Is this all normal new Ethernet connection added without my permission or me using the VM?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?  It's not evident in the screenshot

Comment: VMware creates virtual network connections upon installation and when they are needed. As mentioned previously, try disabling Avast's web "security" and see if TLS works again.

Comment: As i have said the problem went after me restarting the computer twice, the screen shot i have is pretty much all i had
 1. When i was attempting the download an app it failed

 2. I open chrome to see if my internet works and i get this message

 3. I check to see what Ethernet 2 is to see if i can track it

 4. i switch of my wifi see if that connection stays -it stayed

 5. I disable the connection

 6. i turn on my laptop wifi again and check chrome to see it's fixed - it wasn't

 7.i sign out and re login to see if it was fixed - it wasn't

Comment: 8.i restart the computer see if it's fixed and check if that Ethernet 2 came back - it didn't and the problem was still not fixed

9. I restart again and chrome worked and store and internet on the whole worked fine

10. checking log's and stuff to find out what happened and why and posted this.

Comment: I am still not clear on what the "problem" is.  The only problem I see is you have a small spyware infection going on, which your security software caught, and can remove..  Come back and provide more information only after you try disabling the security feature we have described in Avast.

Comment: Furthermore you state hat Malwarebytes does not detect anything but your screenshot say otherwise

Comment: @Ramhound, so they're was a spyware infection??
I ran the `Threat scan`(Malwarebytes) and `Full Scan`(Avast) that's why it detected something... The Antivirus's active in the background but could not detect anything (give me warning notification etc.)  when all the problem occurred
All I know is that I had no internet connection and these screenshot was taken when this all occurred, although I didn't want to problem to spread so I tried fixing this, strangely I totally forgot to run anti virus scan at the time (I panicked).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avast Premium intercepts HTTPS traffic to scan it. ([Official source.](https://www.avast.com/no-no/faq.php?article=AVKB190)) This involves it giving its own TLS certificate to your browser, which lets it decrypt your traffic for analysis; then if the traffic passes Avast's tests, Avast talks to the real site with normal TLS.

You're only getting errors in virtual machines because the VMs don't trust the Avast-generated certificate. Your host machine does because when you installed Avast, it added its root certificate to your machine's trusted store. Since you have no Avast in the VMs (or a different installation), they don't have the root certificate that your host does. Trusting arbitrary certificates/roots would be bad because it would allow actually malicious interceptors to fiddle with or steal your data.

The solution is to disable Avast's web protection, as that will stop the traffic interception. Alternatively, you could try to transfer your host's copy of the root certificate to the VM. Learn more about managing Trusted Root Certificates [at TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx).

To address the results of your threat scan: "Potentially Unwanted Programs" are just annoying things that tend to come in with software installations. If they were doing anything more shady, MalwareBytes would have given you more of an alert. I did some research on MindSpark and it just seems to be a bothersome toolbar. Do tell us if the TLS errors go away after removing the PUPs though.

Comment: +1 for 'disable Avast's web protection', as this eliminates the man-in-the-middle attack going on here.

Comment: It is a simple enough process in IE11, Firefox, or Chrome to create a copy of the certificate within the Virtual Machine and add that certificate to the certificate store.  Of course I don't actually suggest doing that, because the Avast security feature, is literally breaking all TLS/SSL connections in my opinion.  I have an answer that explains the process of copying a certificate to the certificate store if you are interested.

Comment: But the machine/computer I'm running is a normal 64 bit windows OS not VM and all the VM are off so it can't be the VM but what I'm more after is some log or something which can tell me what caused this problem and where, also the fact that it is connected to my computer through Ethernet connection??

Comment: @Dev_anon101 - What?  **You are not being hacked.**

Comment: @Ramhound then what is going on, I also ended up looking at event viewer log's their was a lot of report about new services created by system with no account (which might be normal), but also some service started by `SID NULL` and some `users/IUSR`(I only have one user on the computer) which also had no account information or any other info.

Comment: It is normal. While you don't have a virtual machine turned don you still have a VMWare service installed.  It isn't clear to me what strange behavior you think you have exactly.

Comment: @Dev_anon101 You're almost certainly fine. All manner of things go on in the Security event log; if a virus was obvious enough that it appeared there, MalwareBytes would detect it. To be absolutely sure, disable Avast's web protection, reboot, and try again. *If it's still happening*, click on Chrome's lock icon to see the certificate details.

Comment: @Ben N if this was the case wouldn't chrome be the only thing that didn't work I was on store trying to download an app but was unable to so my whole connection on the computer was down or Avast can be responsible for this too?

Comment: @Dev_anon101 Yes, it could be intercepting all network traffic and looking for HTTP conversations. Please try disabling Avast to see if that is indeed the case.

Comment: There's a Nov. 2014 Malwarebytes [Mindspark toolbars](https://blog.malwarebytes.org/malvertising-2/2014/11/mindspark-toolbars/) article by Pietr Arntz, which notes "There are PUPs and there are toolbars, but Mindspark aka MyWebSearch aka Ask makes plenty of both. Estimates by people who “collect”  these, there must be well over a hundred different toolbars powered by Mindspark." I think I first saw antimalware software flagging their toolbars [in 2006](http://support.moonpoint.com/security/spyware/funwebproducts/090306/), so they've been around for about a decade at least.